# Dynamically assign text to text box in the loop

Tags: vb.net

I want to assign Text to the textBox in the look, I tried

```
       Dim textBoxHB As TextBox = FindName("txt_HB_" + iRecCnt.ToString())

                    Me.Controls(String.Format("txt_HB_" + iRecCnt.ToString()).Text = .HouseBill
```

My Text box name change form txt_HB_1 ,txt_HB_2 and so on, and i want to where iRecCnt has 1,2.. values and Text is coming form .HouseBill

Is there any other way i can try?

Comment: Using `String.Format` there is pointless because there's no format parameters.  Just use `Me.Controls("txt_HB_" & iRecCnt)`.  Apart from that, what actually happens differently to what you want when you execute that code?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the loop with this:

```
Dim boxes = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).Where(Function(b) b.Name.StartsWith("txt_HB_"))
For Each box As TextBox in boxes
    box.Text = .HouseBill
Next
```